# Checking if a value in a Python dictionary is below a threshold in order to increment a value in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a someDictionary similar to this

```
{'1': 0.0011, '2': 0.1100, '3': 0.0123, '4': 0.0002}
```

Also, a masterDictionary with values initially set to 0

```
{'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0}
```

If I create a threshold

```
threshold = 0.01
```

I'd like to check each value in someDictionary and determine if it is `<= threshold` if so, I'd like to increment the value (with the same key) in masterDictionary by 1.

I'm going to do this with several 'someDictionaries' and the keys will not always be in sequential order; so, i'm unable to assume the first key,value in someDictionary will always map to '1' in masterDictionary, etc.

So, after checking each element in someDictionary, masterDictionary would look like

```
{'1': 1, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
someDictionary = {'1': 0.0011, '2': 0.1100, '3': 0.0123, '4': 0.0002}
masterDictionary = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0}
threshold = 0.01

for k, v in someDictionary.items():
    if v <= threshold:
        masterDictionary[k] += 1

print(masterDictionary)
```

**Output**

```
{'4': 1, '1': 1, '2': 0, '3': 0}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another take without the need to initiate the `Dictionary` :

```
from collections import defaultdict

t = defaultdict(int) # <- this will be our master.
d = {'1': 0.0011, '2': 0.1100, '3': 0.0123, '4': 0.0002}

threshold = 0.01

for k,v in d.items():
    t[k] += int(v <= threshold)
```

Comment: @yodish defaultdicts are very powerful for unknown data. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through the keys of the dictionary as the keys appear to be identical between the masterDictionary and the someDictionaries.

```
for key in  masterDictionary.keys():
    if someDictionary[key] <= threshold:
        masterDictionary[key] = 1
```

That could get you the result you are looking for, but only if the keys are the same in all the dictionaries, but they wouldn't have to be in the same order. When you iterate through the keys in a dictionary using this method, you get the label itself, not an index, so the order of the keys is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to address question that would get useful answers